# How To change rss feed url by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, rss

am a javascript newbie making a news app and am using a jquery plugin called zrss feed. The plugin comes with a feature to change the rss feed url by selecting a news source from  a listbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

setRSSFeed('#menu');    

$('#menu').change(function() {
    setRSSFeed(this)
});

function setRSSFeed(obj) {
    var feedurl = $('option:selected', obj).val();

    if (feedurl) {
        $('#test').rssfeed(feedurl);
    }
}
     });
</script>
<select id="menu">    
<optionvalue="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">News</option>
<option value="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC </option>
<option value="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</option>
</select>
```

My problem is that instead of changing the feed url by selecting a newsource from the listbox, i would love to change them by clicking a link. thanks!!

Here is a working example of the problem http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_menu.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">Reuters Oddly Enough News</a>
    <a href="http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv/list">BBC iPlayer TV Listing</a>
    <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss">CNN News</a>
</div>
​
```

and

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    feedurl($(this).attr('href'));
}).first().trigger('click');
```

​
Edit: changed to links as requested and removed feedurl() from here in case OP is copying it into the script, overwriting the real feedurl().

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/HcQuc/4/)

Comment: just one thing: do you need it to set the first one on page load? Edit: I've added that anyway because it looks like you do in your example.

Comment: It deosn't work.....here is a link to a working example of the problem   http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_ticker.html

Comment: that page doesn't show what you asked to be done. where's the drop down that you want converting?

Comment: sorry may be iposted the wrong link ... here is the correct link http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_menu.html    am just trying to use links(href) instead of selecting news sources from the dropdown..nce again thanks